# Rationality of $a^2+b^2$

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I have looked into this topic lately and have not found an answer to the following question.  Is the following true:
If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a + b$ is rational, then $a^2 + b^2$ is rational

Comment: Try $a=\sqrt e$, $b=-\sqrt e$

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your answer.

Comment: it is easy to make both positive as well.  Try $a=\sqrt 2$, $b=2-\sqrt 2$ for example.

Comment: Thank you again.  If permitted, I would like to make one more condition.  Both a and b are irrational while (a+b) > 0.

Comment: My (recent)  example satisfies that.

Comment: You are right.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

**Proof by counter-example**

Take any irrational number $c$ and let $a = \sqrt c$ and $b = -\sqrt c$.

Then $a+b$ will be rational, but $a^2 + b^2$ will be irrational.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was looking for.  What about if (a +b) > 0?